# How to address Could not set the device type in Info.plist issue in appium, while launching the ios simulator?

Tags: ios, appium, inspector

1. I have installed appium version 1.3.6.
2. I have launched appium server to inspect an ios app.
3. I have furnished the error below.

   ```
   Launching Appium with command: '/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node/bin/node'; lib/server/main.js --command-timeout "7200" --pre-launch --log "/tmp/appium.log" --platform-version "8.1" --platform-name "iOS" --app "com.iphonewidget.iphone.testapp" --show-ios-log --device-name "iPhone 6"

   info: [debug] Starting Appium in pre-launch mode

   info: Pre-launching app

   info: [debug] App is an iOS bundle, will attempt to run as pre-existing
   info: [debug] Creating new appium session 255637cf-2d12-41c3-8610-e53f804d229b
   info: [debug] Removing any remaining instruments sockets
   info: [debug] Cleaned up instruments socket /tmp/instruments_sock
   info: [debug] Setting Xcode folder

   info: [debug] Setting Xcode version

   info: [debug] Setting iOS SDK Version

   info: [debug] Getting sdk version from xcrun with a timeout

   info: [debug] iOS SDK Version set to 8.1
   info: [debug] Checking whether instruments supports our device string
   info: [debug] Getting list of devices instruments supports
   info: [debug] Instruments is at: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/instruments

   info: [debug] Getting device string from opts: {"forceIphone":false,"forceIpad":false,"xcodeVersion":"6.1.1","iOSSDKVersion":"8.1","deviceName":"iPhone 6","platformVersion":"8.1"}

   info: [debug] fixDevice is on
   info: [debug] Final device string is: 'iPhone 6 (8.1 Simulator)'
   info: [debug] iOS sim UDID is 4391D23F-BA21-4FB8-8887-0972D2911420

   info: [debug] Detecting automation tracetemplate
   info: [debug] Not auto-detecting udid, running on sim
   info: [debug] Could not parse plist file (as binary) at /Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/com.iphonewidget.iphone.testapp/en.lproj/Localizable.strings
   info: Will try to parse the plist file as XML
   info: [debug] Could not parse plist file (as XML) at /Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/com.iphonewidget.iphone.testapp/en.lproj/Localizable.strings
   warn: Could not parse app Localizable.strings assuming it doesn´t exist
   info: [debug] Creating instruments
   info: On some xcode 6 platforms, instruments-without-delay does not work. If you experience this, you will need to re-run appium with the --native-instruments-lib flag
   info: [debug] Preparing uiauto bootstrap
   info: [debug] Dynamic bootstrap dir: /Users/alk/Library/Application Support/appium/bootstrap
   info: [debug] Dynamic env: 
   {
     "nodePath":"/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node/bin/node",
      "commandProxyClientPath":"/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-uiauto/bin/command-proxy-client.js",
      "instrumentsSock":"/tmp/instruments_sock",
      "interKeyDelay":null,
      "justLoopInfinitely":false,
      "autoAcceptAlerts":false,
      "autoDismissAlerts":false,
      "sendKeyStrategy":"oneByOne"
   }
   info: [debug] Dynamic bootstrap code: // This file is automatically generated. Do not manually modify!
   ...

   error: Could not set the device type in Info.plist
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Unchecking "Prelaunch Application" under General Settings resolved this issue for me.